# Abundant products of iterations of Euler's totient function

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, totient-function, divisor-sum

Let $a_0(n) = n$ and $a_{i+1}(n) = \varphi(a_i(n))$ for $i\geq 0$, where $\varphi(n)$ is Euler's totient function (the number of positive integers less than or equal to $n$ and coprime with $n$). Denote $f(n) = \prod_{k=0}^{\infty}a_k(n)$.

Determine all positive integers $n$ such that the sum of positive divisors of $f(n)$ is strictly
greater than $2f(n)$.

Comment: No, the definition implies $\varphi(1) = 1$.

Comment: My first analysis of the question is that these $f(n)$ numbers are highly composite and most of them should be abundant numbers. I think the proof should just focus on the tail of the totient chain which should end with a series of powers of $2$ followed by "the product of some Fermat primes and a power of two ". If the Fermat primes are $3$ or $5$ then $f(n)$ should be divisible by $6$ or $20$ and this makes the number abundant. it remains to check other general Fermat primes and this probably would give proof that only powers of $2$ do not satisfy the abundance criteria

Answer (score 3):

Let's observe that:
\begin{align*}
a_0(n) &= n \,, \\
a_1(n) &= \varphi(n) \,, \\
a_2(n) &= \varphi(a_1(n)) = \varphi(\varphi(n)) = \varphi^{(2)}(n)\,, \\
... \\
a_k(n) &= \varphi^{(k)}(n)\,,
\end{align*}
where $\varphi^{(k)}(n)$ is $k$ times composition of the totient function. This gives us the function $f(n)$ as
\begin{align*}
f(n) = n\prod_{k=1}^{\infty}\varphi^{(k)}(n) \,.
\end{align*}
Now it is intuitively clear why $\varphi^{(k+1)}(n)\leq\varphi^{(k)}(n)$; that is, we expect the totient function to decrease with each iteration (until it becomes $1$). This means that for a finite number $n$, we have a finite number of elements in the product of $f(n)$.

The problem asks us to find all numbers $n$ that give us $2f(n)<\sigma(f(n))$, where
\begin{align*}
\sigma(f(n)) = \sum_{d|f(n)}d\,,
\end{align*}
is called the divisor function and is the sum of all divisors of $f(n)$.

Numbers that satisfy $2f(n)<\sigma(f(n))$ are called **abundant numbers**. However, we are going to look for numbers $2f(n)>\sigma(f(n))$, where $n$ is referred to as **deficient numbers**. **Deficient numbers contain all odd numbers with distinct primes and all even numbers that are powers of $2$**. Why we choose to look at this case will become apparent soon.

The totient function can be written as
\begin{align*}
\varphi(n) = n\prod_{p|n}\bigg(\frac{p-1}{p}\bigg)\,,
\end{align*}
where $p|n$ means all primes that divide $n$.
The only number that is even and prime is $2$. This means that numbers that are made up of primes greater than $2$ will always give $\varphi(n)$ as an even number. This means that for all $n>2$ we have that $f(n)$ will always be an even number so we do not need to worry about odd deficient numbers.

However, for $n = 2^{m}$ we have
\begin{align*}
\varphi(2^{m}) = 2^{m}\bigg(\frac{2-1}{2}\bigg) = 2^{m-1}\,.
\end{align*}
Thus $f(2^{m})$ is
\begin{align*}
f(2^{m}) = 2^{m+(m-1)+(m-2)+...+1} = 2^{m(m+1)/2}
\end{align*}
and will be a deficient number because $f(2^{m})$ is a power of $2$ (as stated before).

We need to also exclude **perfect numbers** that satisfy $\sigma(f(n)) = 2f(n)$. We already worked out that $f(n)$ is always even and we do not need to worry about odd perfect numbers (still an open problem in number theory). Even perfect numbers are of the form $2^{p-1}(2^{p}-1)$, where $p$ is a prime and $2^{p}-1$ is also a prime (Mersenne prime). We need $n = 2^{p} - 1$ because this is the only term that is odd. Now if we apply the totient function $\varphi(n) = n - 1 = 2^{p}-2$ (because $n$ is prime and will be always coprime with all numbers up to itself), we expect $\varphi(n) = 2^{p-1}$ and this gives us the equation
\begin{align*}
2^{p} - 2 &= 2^{p-1} \\
2^{p-1} - 1 &= 2^{p-2} \,.
\end{align*}
The LHS is odd while RHS is even. So only $p = 2$ is valid and we get $n = 3$ and $f(3)$ will be a perfect number.

In conclusion, the numbers that **do not satisfy the inequality** are $3$ and $2^{m}:m\in\mathbb{N}$. Any other number satisfies the inequality.

Comment: +1, seems correct. But please do make it concise. You've dragged out the answer really long, a lot of trivial stuff can be omitted.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, new around here and will keep it in mind.

Comment: @Schwauss how do we know that for the case of even deficient numbers we need to consider only powers of 2? I was not able to find a corresponding reference.

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deficient_number  Under the section of properties.

Comment: @Schwauss But it says that all powers of two are deficient but not that all even deficient numbers are powers of two?

Comment: I don't think this answers the question